# Why is erwin raising warning ESX-32720 and adding a suffix of "__2" to the name of my new attribute?

Tags: erwin

When adding an attribute named "Column Id", as soon as I leave the name field erwin raises a warning and automatically renames the column by adding a __2 suffix.

Note this is *not* a duplicate attribute name in this entity. I have looked everywhere I can think of where attribute names are managed to see if there is something hidden with the same name but I found nothing.

Here is the full warning:

```
ESX-32720: Setting 'Column Id__2' as the name on the Attribute instead of 'Column Id'.

Object type identifier = 1075838981
Object id = 268
Property type identifier = 1073742126
```